# Chrome and Firefox not remembering session

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

I just switched to the Mac, and I installed Firefox and Chrome. For some reason, I can't get the functionality for opening the tabs and windows from the last session to work either browser.

- Mac OS X 10.6.6
- Firefox 3.6.13
- Chrome 8.0.552.237

I have tried making different profiles and reinstalling the browsers but nothing works.

I have looked everywhere and can't come up with a solution. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**: Safari's "Reopen All Windows from Last Session"  also doesn't restore last session windows.

**EDIT 2**: I just noticed that quitting the browser (versus closing it by clicking the x button) and restarting it *does* resume the last session in every browser.

Answer (score 5):

Seeing your comment, this is because when you click the X on a Mac app, you are only closing the window, not the Application itself (like it does in Windows). Therefore you were still in a 'current' session, and that session had no windows.

Comment: I guess I have still to learn from the intrinsics of the Mac, but it does make sense. Thanks for the answer.